# Custom calendar chart

Tags: google-visualization

I started using google charts. Can I customize google calendar chart such that at beginning it will only show data based on yearly and when click on a year it will show data based on monthly

Comment: no such option exists...

Comment: Thanks,Do you know any other plotting tools which has such option